# cannot import name get_user_model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-registration

I use django-registrations and while I add this code in my admin.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from customer.models import Customer
   from .models import UserProfile
   from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
   from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

   class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
       model = UserProfile
       can_delete = False

   class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
       inlines=(UserProfileInline, )

   admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
   admin.site.register(get_user_model(), UserProfileAdmin)
   admin.site.register(Customer)
```

I receive an error:

```
" cannot import name get_user_model "
in admin.py
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`get_user_model` is available in Django `version >= 1.5` you are probably running Django `version < 1.5`. Upgrade the Django and the problem will be gone.

Or use this instead for Django version < 1.5:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: @Aamir, Whats equivalent property/method in django 1.4?